# MapBox Map Style Spec Sheet - Can't Find Source For Layer (Android)

Tags: android, api, android-studio, mapbox

I am trying to custom style my MapBox map for Android using the style spec sheet outlined [here](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-style-spec), but I am getting a source error.

My current style sheet is:

```
{
  "version": 8,
  "sources": {
    "simple-tiles": {
      "type": "raster",
      "url": "mapbox://mapbox.streets",
      "tileSize": 256
    }
  },
  "layers": [
    {
      "id": "simple-tiles",
      "type": "raster",
      "source": "simple-tiles"
    },
    {
      "id": "water",
      "source": "mapbox-streets",
      "source-layer": "water",
      "type": "fill",
      "paint": {
        "fill-color": "#000000"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

But I am getting this error, and the water features on the map are unaffected:

```
{Map}[Render]: can't find source for layer 'water'
```

I have been unable to find a complete example using a custom style sheet for MapBox for Android.  Any ideas as to why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layer

```
{
  "id": "water",
  "source": "mapbox-streets",
  "source-layer": "water",
  "type": "fill",
  "paint": {
    "fill-color": "#000000"
  }
}
```

Has the line `source: "mapbox-streets"`, but this style doesn't include Mapbox Streets as a source. If you want to use this water layer, you'll need to include the `mapbox-streets` source, which is likely defined in the style you derived this one from. If not, you'll need to remove the `water` layer.

Comment: I was thinking that '"url": "mapbox://mapbox.streets",' in the "sources" section of the base JSON node was defining that source.  Are you saying the source should be specified in the layers array?

Comment: No, the source's id is the key name, which in this style is `simple-tiles` - you would change that to `mapbox-streets`.